# JSF h:button or Primefaces p:button - target _blank

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I set _blank as target of a h:button or p:button?

Right now I have a simple link:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{bean.url}" target="_blank">
 <h:outputText value="Link" />
</h:outputLink>
```

But I wanted it to look like a button (a primefaces styled button if possible) so I decided to change it by a p:button.

```
<p:button value="Link" href="#{bean.url}" />
```

But now I can't set the target value as I want.

Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little javascript will help:

```
<p:button value="Link" onclick="window.open('#{bean.url}'); return false;" />
```

The EL expression will be replaced before javascript is executed.

Comment: Explanation: The `<h:outputLink>` generates HTML `<a>` element which supports `target` attribute, so it's provided as JSF component attribute as well. The `<h/p:button>` generates HTML `<input type="button">` which doesn't support `target` attribute at all, so JSF won't provide a component attribute for it either.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I added the 'return false' to avoid postback.
`<p:button value="Link" onclick="window.open('#{bean.url}'); return false;" />`

Answer (score 0):

I used :

```
<h:form target="_blank">
      <p:commandButton value="Run" action="#{bean.createReport}"  />
    </h:form>
```

and this is ok.

Answer (score -2):

add ajax="false" to primefaces commandButton
set target in p:button, not in form