# Styling one JSF external link to make it look like a button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 3.5, Omnifaces 1.6

I have a group of buttons with icons. The buttons have an action to do on the page (such as delete or add new row in datatable). I want to add new "something" that looks exactly as buttons do, but with an external link. If I click on this new button, new tab/window have to be opened.  For that purpose I am using `p:commandButton` and `h:outputLink`.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.do1}" icon= ...>
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.do2}" icon= ...>

<h:outputLink value="#{bean.url}" target="_blank"> 
  <i class="icon-external-link"></i> 
</h:outputLink>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Related: [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2906582)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- Use a `p:button`, which acts like a link:

  ```
  <p:button href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" value="Go to SO" />
  ```
- If you want a blank target and starting from Primefaces 3.5.5, [there's the chance](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4976) to use the
  `target` attribute directly:

  ```
  <p:button target="_blank" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" value="Go to SO" />
  ```
- When being below PF 3.5.5, you [could do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964711/1199132) some javascript to open it in a blank target:

  ```
  <p:button value="Go to SO" onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')" />
  ```
- All of the choices above **use javascript** to change the browser's
  window location. In order to generate a **bot-harvestable** [HTML
  link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) element, make use of a `h:outputLink` (or just a plain HTML `a` element),
  and style it using Primefaces' classes:

  ```
  <h:outputLink value="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
      <span class="ui-button-text">Go to SO</span>
  </h:outputLink>
  ```

**See also:**

- [window.location.href vs clicking on an Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667512/1199132)

Comment: The `<p:button>` already supports `target` attribute by itself. Noted should be that this all uses JS under the covers which is on contrary to the link not searchbot-indexable per se.

Comment: @BalusC which PF version? Not for me in 3.5 :-(

Comment: Sorry, without I really realized, I've somehow 4.0 RC1 in my playground project. This is indeed absent in 3.5.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thank you for your answer! I've used your suggestion. But in PF 3.5.14 the "target"-attribute is available, so I can actually use it!

Comment: @BalusC Your comment has also helped me, because in PF 3.5.14 the "target" attribute is available. Also thank you for nice CDI features in OF1.6.

Comment: You seriously saved my day... Thank you! @XtremeBiker