# How to open a blank page for an external url with JSF, if target url must be initialy retained from server?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 3.5.14, Omnifaces 1.6

Is there a component in JSF/Prime that looks like a button, but that allows to open a new blank page with an external link ? So unlike a normal link, on click the new page URL must be initialy retained from server   and just then  new page must be opened. Like a commanButton with an action attribute, where a string result of an action method determine the new url.

Of course I can use `p:button` as in [Styling one JSF external link to make it look like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916605/how-to-make-link-to-external-url-in-jsf-that-looks-exactly-as-a-button) but in that case I must  update  link generated by `p:button`, depending on actions made on the page every time. This is not always desirable.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916605/how-to-make-link-to-external-url-in-jsf-that-looks-exactly-as-a-button. Are you concretely asking that you want to invoke a bean action method when the button is pressed and that the external URL is determined based on result of the actual action?

Comment: @BalusC Yes that's right. Sorry for unclear formulating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `target="_blank"` on the parent form in order to submit into a new window and you need to invoke [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html?is-external=true#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) (or OmniFaces' [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.6/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29)) in the action method in order to let the target window send a new GET request on the given URL. Importantly, when you use `<p:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`, you also need to set `ajax="false"` because it doesn't respect `target="_blank"`.

Thus, so:

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    String redirectURL = determineItSomehow();
    Faces.redirect(redirectURL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what I needed. I used `form target="_blank"` on a form with others `commandButton`s which used ajax and it does not disturb.