# How to make a link that looks like a button to an external website (and with parameters, and working for IE8)?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need to make a link that looks exactly like a button, using jsf (and richfaces if helpful) to an external website.

Most of the solutions looks like will not work for an external link. Or are using Primefaces (which I can't).

I have tried:

```
<h:button value="Go" outcome="https://wwws.external-site-in-new-tab.com.br/abc/def.hij?params;#{JSF_EL_param}" />
```

This same link opens in a new window, using an `<a>` element. But does not work for the button.

The error message I see written in the button itself, in my language, portuguese, is:

> "Este botão está desativado porque um caso de navegação não pôde ser
>   correspondido"

something like:

> This button is deactivated because a navigation case could not be matched

Comment: @BalusC not duplicated, I'm using Richfaces, not Primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this: [Styling one JSF external link to make it look like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916605/how-to-make-link-to-external-url-in-jsf-that-looks-exactly-as-a-button)

Try changing

```
<p:button value="Go to SO" onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')" />
```

to

```
<h:button value="Go to SO" onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')" />
```