# External link with jsf or primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to pop up a new window when clicking on a link in order to go to an external URL outside my project, let's say www.google.com, problem is that when ever I try to do this using h:link or p:commandLink the outcome is searched on my project pages, and of course, I get an error. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to use simple HTML  tag because i need to use the property rendered JSF and Pf provides me. Thanks!

Comment: please post whatever code you have tried.

Comment: Use plain HTML and wrap it with `h:panelGroup` or `ui:fragment`, which allow the `rendered` attribute.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963654/jsf-hbutton-or-primefaces-pbutton-target-blank or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724518/jsf2-primefaces-pcommandlink-open-page-in-new-window-tab